# Match any character except those with double quote

Tags: c++, regex

I want a pattern that allows me to match any character except the double quote character ("). To be more clear, I want a regex that will match `Hello World`, but won't match `Hello "World"`.

I'm using C++, so none of the Java regexp utils and such.

Comment: Can you use `std::regex`?

Comment: @Zyx2000 Yes, you can use any `std` classes.

Comment: Language-agnostic regex: `[^\"]*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex

```
^[^"]*$
```

matches any string that doesn't contain quotes.

As a C++ string, that would be `"^[^\"]*$"`, I suppose.

Comment: Don't you need a repetition operator there?  `*`?

Comment: @Alec not if you want to match an empty string (which strictly speaking is a string with no `"` characters)

Comment: @Madbreaks right, what would I want to match against an empty string for? ;)